# Yii2 textInput + label hidden

Tags: javascript, yii2, onchange, hidden

I would like to have a `textInput` with a label **hidden**, what I would like to show later via onChange. I have searched quite a lot, but found nothing. Either I turn it off with `->label(false)`, or leave it on. Is there a way to implement `->label(['style' => 'display: none'])` somehow, as it's working with `->textInput(['style' => 'display: none'])` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `ActiveField::label()` method is the string used as label, the second one is options. You can pass null in first argument to let the ActiveField widget use `getAttributeLabel()` method of your model.

The code should look like this:

```php
$form->field($model, 'attribute')->label(null, ['style' => 'display: none']);
```

Or you can pass options to label directly from field method like this:

```php
$form->field($model, 'attribute', ['labelOptions' => ['style' => 'display: none']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

```
$form->field($model, 'attribute')->label(false);
```

Hope it will helps.